# Probability in a Random Matrix

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, coding-theory

Assume the following random matrix with $N$ rows and $L$ columns consisting of elements in {0,1}.
\begin{bmatrix}
1 &0  & 1 & ...&0 \\ 
1 & 0 & 0& ... &1 \\ 
1 & 0 & 1 & ... & 0\\
\vdots& \vdots&\vdots&\ddots& \vdots\\
0 & 0 & 0 & ... & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & ... & 1
\end{bmatrix}
The probability of an element being a $1$, (independent of the matrix elements) is $\epsilon$. What is the probability of at most $K$ elements equal to $1$ in a column?

My own calculation is 
$P=\sum_{k=0}^{K}\begin{pmatrix}N\\ k\end{pmatrix}\epsilon^k(1-\epsilon)^{(N-k)}$, but I am not sure about it since does not depend on $L$.

Verification of the above equation, an approximate, or an educated guess, all would be useful.

Comment: Your calculation is correct if there is only one column. Here is another question: "What is the probability that the number of 1's is less than K in every column?" Isn't this the question?

Comment: Yes. Less than, or equal to K in all columns. Is it something like $P^L$?

Comment: Since the columns are independent and the probabilities are the same for every column...

Comment: Assume $X=1-(1-\epsilon)^L$. Can you tell me how the above $P^L$ is related to $\sum_{k=0}^{K}\begin{pmatrix}N\\ k\end{pmatrix}X^k(1-X)^{(N-k)}$? I think the latter is the probability of K rows have at least one 1. Right?

Comment: $1-(1-\epsilon)^L$ is the probability that there is at least one $1$ in a given row. The sum above is the probability that there are at most $K$ such rows. This is a sufficient but not a necessary condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let $N=L=3$ and $K=2$.

The following matrix satisfies that there are at most two rows having at least one $1$'s:

$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{c|c|c}
      1&1&1\\
\hline
      0&0&1\\
\hline
0&0&0
    \end{array}
\right] $$

It follows that every column contains at most two $1$'s

In the following matrix there are three rows containing at most one $1$'s, yet none of the columns contain more than two $1$'s.

$$ \left[
    \begin{array}{c|c|c}
      1&1&1\\
\hline
      1&0&0\\
\hline
0&0&1
    \end{array}
\right] $$

In general the probability that one given column contains at most $K$ $1$'s is - as you wrote:
$$P=\sum_{k=0}^{K}\begin{pmatrix}N\\ k\end{pmatrix}\epsilon^k(1-\epsilon)^{(N-k)}.$$

Since the columns are independent, the answer to the OQ is $P^L$.